# How do I truncate a 64-bit hash into a 32-bit hash?

Tags: hash, integer, truncate, bitmask

If I want to produce a 32-bit has from a 64-bit hash is it sufficient to simply mask the 64-bit value to 32 bits? By "sufficient" I mean I want the 32-bit hash to have as even distribution as the 64-bit hash, but in 32-bit space.

If masking is not sufficient, does XORing the high order bits with the low order bits maintain  that distribution, or is there something more appropriate?

For this solution, cryptographic integrity does not matter.

Comment: @MattBall That'll do, and answers the question very well -- thanks!